# Executing a jar with arguments, but it's not accepting argument whatever I give in ProcessBuilder method

Tags: java, methods, argument-passing

I am executing a .jar with arguments that I have written below, it's executing the jar and is waiting for the arguments. **I give arguments, it's not accepting**, this same method is working fine for the other .jar execution with many arguments that I've tried. What can be the problem?

Here is the code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //BufferedReader br = null;
    System.out.println("starting");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java","-jar","C:/Tcserver/tcclient/lib/tbrowser.jar","Browser.1");
    try{
        Process p = pb.start();
        OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream ();
        InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream ();
        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream ();


        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader (isr);
        String line;
        while((line = buff.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to make your question title a bit more descriptive, the one you've chosen is... interesting...

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not reading?" Do you know the Java is executing? What is it not reading?